# Prevent other terminals from running a script while another terminal is using it

Tags: bash, unix, lockfile

I would like prevent other terminals from running a certain script whenever another terminal is running it however in bash but I'm not quite sure on how I would be able to go about in doing it. Any help or tip could be greatly appreciated!

In example:
When that script is being run on another terminal, all other terminals would be unable to run that certain script as well. And display a message "UNDER MAINTENANCE".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the concept of a "lockfile."  For example:

```
if [ -f ~/.mylock ]; then
    echo "UNDER MAINTENANCE"
    exit 1
fi
touch ~/.mylock

# ... the rest of your code

rm ~/.mylock
```

To get fancier/safer, you can "trap" the `EXIT` signal to remove it automatically at the end:

```
trap 'rm ~/.mylock' EXIT
```

Comment: That's the perfect race condition

Answer (score 2):

To avoid race conditions, you could use `flock(1)` along with a
lock file.  There is [one flock(1) implementation](https://github.com/discoteq/flock)
which claims to work on Linux, BSD, and OS X.  I haven't seen one
explicitly for Unix.
There is some interesting discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29185116/bash-scripting-reader-writer-lock).

**UPDATE:**
I found a really clever way from Randal L. Schwartz [here](https://plus.google.com/+RandalLSchwartz/posts/QcrqvT3mUdy).  I really like this one.  It relies on having `flock(1)` and `bash`, and it uses the script itself as its own lockfile.  Check this out:

`/usr/local/bin/onlyOne` is a script to obtain the lock

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 200< $0
if ! flock -n 200; then
    echo "there can be only one"
    exit 1
fi
```

Then `myscript` uses `onlyOne` to obtain the lock (or not):

```
#!/bin/bash
source /usr/local/bin/onlyOne
# The real work goes here.
echo "${BASHPID} working"
sleep 120
```

Comment: I left in the _Highlander_ references.  It seemed mildly sacrilegious to remove them.

Answer (score 2):

Use `flock` and put this on top of your script:

```
if ! flock -xn /path/to/lockfile ; then
    echo "script is already running."
    echo "Aborting."
    exit 1
fi
```

Note: `path/to/lockfile` could be the path to your script. Doing so would avoid to create an extra file.