# Shell Script - Delete a file at the end of a method

Tags: bash, shell, locking, sh

I have a shell script that runs a function that exists in another shell script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash    
source docker_util.sh
log_exec docker_login

#More stuff here
```

My function looks like following.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker_login() {
    counter=1
    while [ $counter -le 10 ]
    do
         if { set -C; 2>/dev/null >/var/tmp/docker-credstore-lock.lock; }; then
           break
         else
           sleep 10
           ((counter++))
         fi
    done

    #Run some stuff here

}
```

I am looking for the best way to delete the `docker-credstore-lock.lock` file at the end of executing `docker_login` function. I am aware of using `trap "rm -f /var/tmp/docker-credstore-lock.lock" EXIT` , but the issue with this is this only runs once the original shell script is exiting, so the lock will be there even after the `docker_login` method is finished.

I have also thought of using following block in the `docker_login` method, but this will not be executed in a ctrl+c event, which is problematic.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
docker_login() {
    counter=1
    while [ $counter -le 10 ]
    do
         if { set -C; 2>/dev/null >/var/tmp/docker-credstore-lock.lock; }; then
           break
         else
           sleep 10
           ((counter++))
         fi
    done

    {
        #Run some stuff here
     } || {rm -f /var/tmp/docker-credstore-lock.lock}

}
```

Any idea on the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What you call _lock_ is a file. If you delete a file in one script, it does not pop up magically in a different file. You don't even seem to use `flock`, but just rely on `set -C` as a guard (can't tell how reliable this is).

Comment: My system is on OSX. From what I read, flock seem to be not supported for OSX. Is there any alternative?

Comment: This seems to have been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526651/mac-os-x-equivalent-of-linux-flock1-command).

Comment: Just an idea: Would perhaps [chflags](https://ss64.com/osx/chflags.html) help?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the second solution AND trap the KILL signal in the script of docker_login.

I mean

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
trap "rm -f /var/tmp/docker-credstore-lock.lock" KILL

docker_login() {
    counter=1
    while [ $counter -le 10 ]
    do
         if { set -C; 2>/dev/null >/var/tmp/docker-credstore-lock.lock; }; then
           break
         else
           sleep 10
           ((counter++))
         fi
    done

    {
        #Run some stuff here
     } || {rm -f /var/tmp/docker-credstore-lock.lock}

}
```

By the way, I think the rm command in the docker_login won't ever executed if the previous block exit with false value

Comment: As per my understanding, the rm block only gets executed if there is a false exit in the first block before ||. If it returns successfully, `rm` will not get executed.